# How To Architect Real-time Website Database

Tags: database-design, architecture, real-time, dashboard

I'm creating a website to monitor a set of tables in my production system in real-time.  We want to expand this website in the future to monitor more of the system.  I want to build the proper database architecture to support this in the future.  I'm worried that the website accessing the production databases could impact the performance of the production system.  What is the recommended approach for dealing having a real-time website that monitors the system?  Do I replicate the production data to a different non-production database that the website uses?  Do I run jobs on the production data and create a summary table for the website to use?  Should I just have the website access the data from the production system?

I'm new to this, so any help pointing me in the right direction would be most helpful.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: This seems a bit broad for the scope of a StackOverflow question. To develop a dashboard, you'd need to make a whole host of decisions, including considering how large, mission critical, and frequently accessed the tables were. Depending on the server infrastructure, you could use a variety of languages, frameworks and commercial products.

Comment: As Keith said it's a bit broad. It also depends upon ywhat sort monitoring you are talking about, performance, data validity etc.  But generally speaking your monitoring should not break your production.